# How to Reconcile Apparent Discrepancy in this Algorithm's Runtime?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I'm currently working through *Algorithms* by Dr. Jeff Erickson. The following is an algorithm presented in the book:

```
NDaysOfChristmas(gifts[2 .. n]):

    for i ← 1 to n
        Sing “On the ith day of Christmas, my true love gave to me”

        for j ← i down to 2
            Sing “j gifts[j],”
        if i > 1
            Sing “and”

        Sing “a partridge in a pear tree.”
```

Here's the runtime analysis of the algorithm presented by Dr. Erickson:

> The input to *NDaysOfChristmas* is a list of $n − 1$ gifts, represented here as an array. It’s quite easy to show that the singing time is $\Theta(n^{2})$; in particular, the singer mentions the name of a gift $\sum_{i=1}^ni = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ times (counting the partridge in the pear tree). It’s also easy to see that during the first $n$ days of Christmas, my true love gave to me exactly $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}j = \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6} = \Theta(n^3)$ gifts.

I can't seem to grasp how it is possible your $``$true love$"$ had given you $\Theta(n^3)$ gifts, while a computer scientist looking at this algorithm would say the algorithm's runtime complexity is $\Theta(n^2)$?

Dr. Erickson also says the name of a gift is mentioned $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ times, which is in $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: I can say "12" in one step but it gives 12 gifts. And in 12 steps, I can talk about 12 gifts + 11 gifts + 10 gifts + 9 gifts + ... + 1 gift = (12)(13)/2 gifts.  So I can *state* "gave to me" Theta(n^2) times which described Theta(n^3) gifts

Comment: if you made an operation for every gift given, you would replace the single instruction "my true love gave to me 5 golden rings" with another forloop running i=1..5 with an instruction give(ring). So if you saw your line " Sing f gifts[j]" with a loop from 1 to j, then you would probably more easily see Theta(n^3) gifts

Comment: Each time that a type of gift is mentioned it comes with a multiplicity. The partridge in a pear tree is given one each time, since they say "**a** partridge in a pear tree". The gifts in the array `gifts`, however, are given more than one at a time. Look at the part `“j gifts[j],”`. The `j`-th gift in `gifts` is given `j` units at a time. In the last formula in the quoted text, there is a typo. There is a missing $j$ inside the inner sum.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I didn’t realize there was a multiplicity involved with the gifts. This totally clarifies the issue.